# C++ How To Read First Couple Bytes Of Function? (32 bit Machine)

Tags: c++, security, assembly, memory, tampering

Let's say I have a function like this (completely random, I just wrote it up in like 30 seconds for an example)

```
bool exampleAuthetnication(char *a, char *b)
{
    bool didAuthenticate = false;
    if(strcmp(a, b) == 0)
    {
        didAuthenticate = true;
    }

    if(didAuthenticate)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        stopExecutable();
        return false;
    }
}
```

How would I go about reading the first few bytes of this function?

I've come up with this

```
int functionByteArray[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    functionByteArray[i] = *(int*)(((int)&exampleAuthetnication) + (0x04 * i));
}
```

The logic behind it being that we get the memory address of our function (in this case `exampleAuthetnication()`) then we cast to int pointer then dereferance to get the value of the current line of bytes we are trying to read then store in `functionByteArray`, but it does not seem to work properly. What am I doing wrong? Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Comment: "but it does not seem to work properly" Why? Whats the result and what result did you expect?

Comment: @tkausl the result seems to be just some random numbers, They do not mach up with what they should be based off viewing the function in IDA

Comment: Thats probably because you read 32 bits as LittleEndian and IDA shows the data as bytes.

Comment: @tkausl also, even if I change the first few lines of this function (exampleAuthetnication) the bytes stored in functionByteArray dont change?

Comment: You don't explain why you want to get the first few bytes of the code, and on which machine and operating system (and ABI) you want to do that

Comment: Can you put in your question the unexpected values you are seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by "first few bytes of this function", exactly? Are you trying to extract parts of the compiled program from itself?

Comment: Related: [How to read binary executable by instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153556/how-to-read-binary-executable-by-instructions) has an answer that hexdumps the first 10 bytes of `main`, by casting a function pointer to a `const char*`.  This does work in practice on typical C implementations, although as Basile's answer shows, it's not guaranteed by the standard, and there may be some real implementations where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In theory (according to the C++11 standard) you cannot even cast a function pointer into a data pointer (on [Harvard architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) code and data sit in different memories and different address spaces). Some operating systems or processors might also forbid reading of executable [code segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) (read about [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)).

In practice, on x86-64 (or 32 bits x86) running some operating system like Linux or Windows, a function code is a sequence of *bytes* and can be unaligned, and sits in the (common) virtual address space of its process. So you should at least have `char functionByteArray[40];` and you might use [std::memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) from `<string>` and do some

```
std::memcpy(functionByteArray, (char*)&exampleAuthetnication,
            sizeof(functionByteArray));
```

At last your code is wrong because -on x86-64 notably- `int` have not the same size as pointers (so `(int)&exampleAuthetnication` is losing the upper bytes of the address). You should at least use `intptr_t`. And `int` has stronger alignment constraints than the code.

BTW, you might also ask your compiler to show the generated assembler code. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile your `exampleAhtetnication` C++ code with `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S`  and look into the generated `.s` file.

Notice that the C++ compiler might [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) to the point of "removing" some function from the code segment (e.g. because that function has been inlined everywhere), or split the function code in several pieces, or put that 
`exampleAhtetnication` code "inside" another function...

Comment: if I didn't cast to `(int)` I could not compile and would get errors that is why I did it like that. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: I may be wrong but I think if you use the address of a function that it will use the non-inlined variant.

Comment: Yes. But the compiler might still optimize to split its code, or emit a jump inside *another* function which has inlined `exampleAhtetnication`.

Comment: @Coder1337: The issue is that you used `int` instead of `uintptr_t`.   But you don't need to cast to an integer type at all, because you only needed to add, and C++ allows addition between integers and non-`void` pointers.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, some compiler *might* do that, but gcc doesn't.  If you take the address of a function, you will get a stand-alone definition of it even if the compilation unit / program didn't otherwise need one.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Isn't that up nto the linker to decide? Or does GCC stuff it in a larger section leaving the linker no choice? (I've always found it weird that `--ffunction-sections` works so poorly on GCC)

Comment: I am not so sure. IIRC, some weird optimization options might do strange things.

Comment: @MSalters: if the function is `static` or `inline`, it's the compiler has the option of not emitting a stand-alone definition.  If not, only link-time optimization could drop it, I think, but it won't be able to if, after optimization, a valid pointer to the function is needed.  (But I wouldn't call that "the linker".)

Answer (score -1):

C++ source code is not a list of instructions for a computer to perform; it is a collection of statements that *describe the meaning of a program*.

Your compiler interprets these statements and produces an actual sequence of instructions (via the assembly stage) that can actually be executed in our physical reality.

The language used to do so does not provide any facilities for examining the bytes that make up the compiled program. All of your attempts to cast function pointers and the like may randomly give you some similar data, via the magic of undefined behaviour, but the results are just that: undefined.

If you wish to examine the compiled executable, do so from outside of the program. You could use a hex editor, for example.